# 3D drawing program to pose human figures (like Windows Poser)

Tags: software-rec, animation, 3d

Are there any good Linux-alternatives to the Windows-program Poser - a program that allows you to manipulate human-figures (dressed in skins) in a humanly way (ie. with the restriction a human body impose on body-movement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used this and am familiar with Poser in concept, but have never used it. I found the alternatives to  Poser here: http://alternativeto.net/software/poser/

[MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/)

> MakeHuman is a free, Open Source, interactive modeling tool for creating custom 3D human characters. These characters can be modeled in minutes and can then be used with many other modeling and rendering programs to incorporate realistic human figures into computer generated images and animations. Features that make this software unique include the tetra-parametric GUI© and the Natural Pose System©, for advanced muscular simulation.